# Visual Studio 2015 UnauthorizedAccessException in Debug Only

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have spent some time today on this issue reading a number of similar posts. Running this in Release is okay - no such error or issue. In Debug I am not able to open any text file. Note I am running Visual Studio 2015 in Admin mode as noted on post I have found and read on here. But I can not figure out what the issue is. Can someone point me the right direction.

**Debug Output from catch:**

> Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
>   The file could not be read:
>  Access to the path 'D:\TestFiles\Basic
>   TextFiles\TextFile.txt' is denied.

```
    private void Open_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "Rich Text Format (*.rtf)|*.rtf|CSharp (*.cs)|*.cs|XAML Format (*.xaml)|*.xaml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Stream sr = new FileStream(dlg.FileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    TextRange range = new TextRange(rtbEditor.Document.ContentStart, rtbEditor.Document.ContentEnd);
                    range.Load(sr, DataFormats.Rtf);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try deleting/moving the file/ `D:\TestFiles\Basic TextFiles\TextFile.txt'`

Comment: I can not open any text file on C: | D: | S: drives. AKA any drive on my laptop. Tried moving it but same results. Release has no issue.

Comment: I suspect even release has this issue, you don't see exception as `Debug.WriteLin`e works only in debug mode.

Comment: Check the file attributes, I strongly feel file is readonly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks to Hari Prasad I was able to figure out my issue. My test text files I have been using got marked as read only in all my folders. Not 100% sure but it seems to be done by a bitDefender feature for ransomeware. Moving a file or delete and create new did not fix my issue. But after looking at it as some older simular posts note about read-only I saw they are all set as read only. Unchecking that solved my problem and removing this folder from bitdefenders ransomeware monitoring feature.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue in trying to write a UnitTest for a WCF Web service. In this case I had to start up inetmgr - and on the Default Web Site - Edit Permissions - then on the Security Tab find the IIS_USRS and the WRITE permission was not there. Click Edit - and check that permission and then the Unauthorized Exception stopped. Since the service is using IIS_EXPRESS in VS2019 - I had not set that on Default Web Site -which is the context of a new web service.